# Set a defalt filter in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I'm constructing a dashboard with data for a university which can be filtered to show just one college at a time. I am using a filter on p-value so that only relevant features display for each college.

When no college is selected, Tableau is designed to show the full data set. However, that requires filtering on some aggregation of the p-values, prevalence of features, retention rates, etc. Aggregation here is misleading.

How can I set a default filter? Is there another way to avoid aggregating the colleges?

Comment: can you please share some sample screenshots ? you existing calculated fields etc

Comment: Or try Single Value and Remove "Show all Value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that I can apply a filter to my dashboard, then upload it to the server. The filter I applied when uploading will be applied when someone first opens the dashboard.

To keep viewers from seeing the dashboard with no filter applied, I used the filter action setting "Clearing the selection will: leave the filter". The previous filter will remain active until a new filter is selected by the viewer.